# Moss 2007 on windows 7 installation compatibility

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, windows-7

I have the machine with installed the Windows 7 Enterprise N edition. I have installed the sql server 2008 also there . so can i install  MOSS 2007 on such connfiguration? if not what should i do. i tried to install but showing not compitible prompt. what have to do? is wss3.0 already present in windows 7 like windows server 2003 ? I know i can do this by virtual PC installation , but i don't want right away to virtualize machine.

Answer (score 0):

MOSS 2007 is only supported by Microsoft on Windows Server operating systems:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28office.12%29.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/cc262485%28v=office.12%29)

This is a real pain, as it means developers have to work on remote servers (what I do :/) or run VMs with a Windows Server OS.

I believe there are some workarounds to get it running on Windows 7, but to be honest this is not supported and it's probably not worth the trouble:

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/weslbo/archive/2009/05/08/how-to-install-moss-2007-sp2-on-windows-7-rc-build-7100.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/weslbo/how-to-install-moss-2007-sp2-on-windows-7-rc-build-7100)

[http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/05/07/running-sharepoint-on-windows-7.aspx](https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/running-sharepoint-on-windows-7)